# Undiscovered unit test in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to run/debug mocha test from VS 2017, but it doesn't discover my testcases:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: have you installed [Chutzpah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.ChutzpahTestAdapterfortheTestExplorer) ?

Comment: @LucaCappa. I haven't. I will try it. Thx

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but Mocha tests won't show if you only add a plain javascript file to the project and then put some Mocha tests in that file. In VS2017 you have to specifically choose the item type 'Mocha Unit Test' when you 'add item' to the project otherwise the tests aren't discovered. This is because In the 'njsproj' file VS specifies if the file is to be considered a test or not.

Comment: Actually just found this, explains it all... [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Test-Explorer)